# Win32: Reloading theme after theme-related registry changes?

Tags: windows, winapi, rust, reverse-engineering, sendmessage

There's a couple theming related registry keys that I'm editing through a personal tool:

- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize\AppsUseLightTheme` (to change light/dark mode preference)
- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent\AccentPalette` (to change taskbar color)

I'd really like to update the theme appearance on the fly, but the problem is these changes don't take effect until after restart. The "Theme Settings" in the native System Settings edits the same registry keys, but also manages to update the color of the taskbar etc on the fly.

To understand how the native System Settings is reloading the theme, I've tried monitoring the outgoing window messages in Spy++ and inspecting the API calls in WinDbg. It broadcasts `WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED` and `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` (with `"ImmersiveColorSet"`). But attempting to do the same doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever:

```rust
fn reload_theme() -> Result<()> {
  unsafe {
    // Send message to all top-level windows.
    let broadcast_handle = HWND(0xffff);

    SendNotifyMessageW(
      broadcast_handle,
      WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED,
      WPARAM(3812725153), // Arbitrary value
      LPARAM(1),          // Arbitrary value
    );

    SendNotifyMessageW(
      broadcast_handle,
      WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
      WPARAM(0),
      LPARAM(w!("ImmersiveColorSet").as_ptr() as isize), // Equivalent to L"ImmersiveColorSet" in c++
    );

    Ok(())
  }
}
```

One other discovery so far is that always updating the key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\AccentColor` causes a reload. There are still elements here and there that don't update though.

How can you "reload" the Windows theme without restarting after theme-related registry changes?

Comment: It's quite likely broadcasting the message is merely a courtesy of the system to inform applications. Effecting the change itself is probably done in a part of the system that deliberately hasn't been exposed to application control. MS has gotten more conservative over the years about granting third-party applications access to system settings that normally should be controlled directly by the user alone, because whenever they do offer access it's invariably abused. For every desirable, courteous tool that a user might want to change settings, there are a dozen that don't ask.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am struggling with this issue as well:
https://superuser.com/questions/1769487/windows-does-not-respect-theme-switch-done-by-registry

Comment: @EyalCohen Still on the lookout for a solution to this. Let me know if you make any new developments :)

Comment: I found out that turning transparency effect off and on reloads the values from registry.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast theme changed message with `SendMessageTimeoutW`:

```rust
use windows::w;
use windows::Win32::Foundation::{HWND, LPARAM, WPARAM};
use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{SendMessageTimeoutW, SMTO_BLOCK, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED};

// ...

let hwnd_broadcast = HWND(0xffff);

SendMessageTimeoutW(
    hwnd_broadcast,
    WM_SETTINGCHANGE,
    WPARAM::default(),
    LPARAM(w!("ImmersiveColorSet").as_ptr() as isize),
    SMTO_BLOCK,
    1000,
    None,
);

SendMessageTimeoutW(
    hwnd_broadcast,
    WM_DWMCOLORIZATIONCOLORCHANGED,
    WPARAM::default(),
    LPARAM::default(),
    SMTO_BLOCK,
    1000,
    None,
);
```